# Resize UIView from bottom to top

Tags: swift, animation, uiview, resize

I know that I can resize a `UIView` like that:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.myView.frame.size.height = 300
}, completion: { finished in
    self.open = false
    println("closed!")
})
```

But I need to resize the view so that it resizes upwards(bottom to top). At the moment the UIView expands down.

Is there a way to do that, without turning the UIView upside down?